# Access SQL Syntax error: missing operator

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error

I am trying to convert a T-SQL query to MS Access SQL and getting a syntax error that I am struggling to find. My MS Access SQL query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO IndvRFM_PreSort (CustNum, IndvID, IndvRScore, IndRecency, IndvFreq, IndvMonVal )
    SELECT 
        IndvMast.CustNum, IndvMast.IndvID, IndvMast.IndvRScore, 
        IndvMast.IndRecency, IndvMast.IndvFreq, IndvMast.IndvMonVal
    FROM 
        IndvMast 
    INNER JOIN 
        OHdrMast ON IndvMast.IndvID = OHdrMast.IndvID 
    INNER JOIN 
        MyParameterSettings on 1=1].ProdClass
    INNER JOIN 
        [SalesTerritoryFilter_Check all that apply] ON IndvMast.SalesTerr = [SalesTerritoryFilter_Check all that apply].SalesTerr
    WHERE 
        (((OHdrMast.OrdDate) >= [MyParameterSettings].[RFM_StartDate]))
    GROUP BY 
        IndvMast.CustNum, IndvMast.IndvID, IndvMast.IndvRScore, 
        IndvMast.IndRecency, IndvMast.IndvFreq, IndvMast.IndvMonVal, 
        [CustTypeFilter_Check all that apply].IncludeInRFM, 
        [ProductClassFilter_Check all that apply].IncludeInRFM, 
        [SourceCodeFilter_Check all that apply].IncludeInRFM, 
        IndvMast.FlgDontUse
```

I have reviewed differences between MS Access SQL and T-SQL at http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2013/05/what-are-differences-between-access-sql.html and a few other locations but with no luck.

All help is appreciated.

update: I have removed many lines trying to find the syntax error and I am still getting the same error when running just (which runs fine using T-SQL):

```
SELECT 
    IndvMast.CustNum, IndvMast.IndvID, IndvMast.IndvRScore, 
    IndvMast.IndRecency, IndvMast.IndvFreq, IndvMast.IndvMonVal
FROM 
    IndvMast 
INNER JOIN 
     OHdrMast  ON IndvMast.IndvID = OHdrMast.IndvID    
INNER JOIN 
     [My Parameter Settings] ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Are you missing a final parenthesis in the `HAVING` statement?

Comment: why HAVING (((IndvMast.IndRecency)>(date()-7200)) AND (([CustTypeFilter_Check all that apply].IncludeInRFM)=1) AND (([ProductClassFilter_Check all that apply].IncludeInRFM)=1) AND (([SourceCodeFilter_Check all that apply].IncludeInRFM)=1) AND ((IndvMast.FlgDontUse) Is Null)) instead of WHERE clause?

Comment: @MarkC. There is an extra closing parenthesis, nice catch.

Comment: @MarkC. added a closing parenthesis to having clause. Still getting error: `Syntax Error(missing operator) in query espression 'IndvMast.IndvID = OHdrMast.IndvID ........ = [SalesTerritoryFilter_Check all that apply].SalesTer'`

Comment: @peggy Then there is another issue. Start deleting things until you get a successful run and then begin adding them again and let us know what actually breaks it.

Comment: @peggy please re-post your query. what's up with `1=1apply]`?

Comment: @peggy you still have `MyParameterSettings on 1=1].ProdClass`?

Comment: @MarkC. it seems to be the `inner join MyParameterSettings on 1=1`... not sure how to replace this using access sql

Comment: Ignoring any other errors - the join statements in Jet like brackets.  eg:  `FROM ((First Join ON A=B) Second Join ON A=C) Third Join ON A=D` so the FROM statement in your last bit of SQL should be: `FROM (IndvMast INNER JOIN OHdrMast ON IndvMast.IndvID = OHdrMast.IndvID) INNER JOIN [My Parameter Settings] ON 1=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of items in your query that should also have failed in any SQL-compliant database:

1. You have fields from tables in `GROUP BY` not referenced in `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses.
2. Number of fields in `SELECT` query do not match number of fields in `INSERT INTO` clause.
3. The *MyParameterSettings* table is not properly joined with valid `ON` expression.

Strictly MS Access SQL items:

1. For more than one join, MS Access SQL requires paired parentheses but even this can get tricky if some tables are joined together and their paired result joins to outer where you get nested joins.
2. Expressions like `ON 1=1` must be used in `WHERE` clause and for cross join tables as *MyParameterSettings* appears to be, use comma-separated tables.
3. For above reasons and more, it is advised for beginners to this SQL dialect to use the Query Design builder providing table diagrams and links (if you have the MS Access GUI .exe of course). Then, once all tables connect graphically with at least one field selected, jump into SQL view for any nuanced scripting logic.

Below is an adjustment to SQL statement to demonstrate the parentheses pairings and for best practices, uses table aliases especially with long table names.

```
INSERT INTO IndvRFM_PreSort (CustNum, IndvID, IndvRScore, IndRecency, IndvFreq, IndvMonVal)

SELECT 
    i.CustNum, i.IndvID, i.IndvRScore, i.IndRecency, i.IndvFreq, i.IndvMonVal
FROM 
    [MyParameterSettings] p, (IndvMast i
INNER JOIN 
    OHdrMast o ON i.IndvID = o.IndvID) 
INNER JOIN 
    [SalesTerritoryFilter_Check all that apply] s ON i.SalesTerr = s.SalesTerr
WHERE 
    (o.OrdDate >= p.[RFM_StartDate])
GROUP BY 
    i.CustNum, i.IndvID, i.IndvRScore, i.IndRecency, i.IndvFreq, i.IndvMonVal
```

And in your smaller SQL subset, the last table does not need an `ON 1=1` condition and may be redundant as well in SQL Server. Simply a comma separate table will suffice if you intend for cross join. The same is done in above example:

```
SELECT  
    IndvMast.CustNum, IndvMast.IndvID, IndvMast.IndvRScore, 
    IndvMast.IndRecency, IndvMast.IndvFreq, IndvMast.IndvMonVal
FROM 
    [My Parameter Settings], IndvMast
INNER JOIN 
     OHdrMast ON IndvMast.IndvID = OHdrMast.IndvID
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there are some errors in your query, the first (more important).

Why do you use `HAVING` clause to add these conditions?

```
HAVING (((IndvMast.IndRecency)>(date()-7200))
AND (([CustTypeFilter_Check all that apply].IncludeInRFM)=1)
AND (([ProductClassFilter_Check all that apply].IncludeInRFM)=1)
AND (([SourceCodeFilter_Check all that apply].IncludeInRFM)=1)
AND ((IndvMast.FlgDontUse) Is Null))
```

`HAVING` usually used about conditions on aggregate functions (COUNT, SUM, MAX, MIN, AVG), for scalar value you must put in `WHERE` clause.

The second: You have 12 parenthesis opened and 11 closed in HAVING clause

Comment: The query works fine in sql with the having clause. Added a closing parenthesis and still getting `Syntax Error(missing operator) in query espression 'IndvMast.IndvID = OHdrMast.IndvID ........ = [SalesTerritoryFilter_Check all that apply].SalesTer'`